# Mapping entity through an aggregation of one columne

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I've recently runned into a problem, having a single table with multiple columns as a PK. I was wondering if there is any elegant solution using Hibernate 5 to map this table through an aggregation of one of those fields.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_product(
    email varchar(255) not null,
    product_name varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (email, product_name)
);
```

This table is totally independent. There is no User or Product table(that would make it way easier) since all user info will be stored in cognito.

The resulting entity I'm looking for is something like this:

```
public class User {

    private String email;
    private Set<String> products;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the annotation @EmbeddedId?

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositeUserProductId {

   private String email;
   private String product_name;

}


@Entity
public class UserProduct {

   @EmbeddedId
   private CompositeUserProductId compositeId;
```

}

Comment: Yes, but it could be that an email has multiple products, and that would force me to have a List of UserProduct. I would like to avoid that if possible and try to have an aggregation of Products instead.

Answer (score 0):

@Skeith, have you tried below?

```
public class User {

    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<String> products = new ArrayList<>();    
}
```

Comment: products is not mapped to any other entity, so @OneToMany won't work here